# Davening alone on the yamim noraim

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book, high-holidays

I found a Kof-K publication titled "Tefillah When Davening Alone" and learned that there is more to it than just skipping the parts that require a minyan (see [here](https://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol16Issue5.pdf)).

Now I seek a similar publication that describes davening alone on the yamim noraim (High Holidays).

Comment: There will be lots and lots of them in the coming weeks, especially as Israel is considering a closure similar to Pesach. In any case, many elderly, sick and otherwise at-risk people will need precise instructions so lots of instructions will come out soon

Comment: Why is this so different from any other day?

Comment: @DoubleAA Well, for one, there is no Kol Nidre on most days. (Your question was totally unexpected and suprising.)

Comment: @YehudaW That is what is so different? Most days have Shmone Esrei, Shema, and Torah reading. These days are pretty much the same. If you find some particular exception which you aren't sure if it requires a minyan, you can certainly ask about it (as apparently you are unsure about Kol Nidrei? I don't see why you'd think it requires a minyan to say)

Comment: @DoubleAA Kol Nidrei is a beit din, which is why we say it before night. So may it be said alone?  Of course we need 3 for Hatarat nedarim.  In any case, there are subtleties for the daily, shabbat, and rosh hodesh davening, as described in the link I provided. So I am thinking that there may be subtleties in the Yamim Noraim (and chagim) davening as well.

Comment: @DoubleAA various reasonable questions: should you blow the shofar during shemoneh esrei?  should you say the piyutim of selichos?  should you say the avodah?  should you do 2 viduyim per tefillah?

Comment: @YehudaW I'm not sure what you mean by "kol nidrei is a beit din"

Comment: @robev This URL says, in part, "The Rosh answers that since everyone recites "Kol Nidrei" quietly with the Chazan, they all serve as a Beis Din of three men (Hedyotos) to annul each other's Nedarim." https://dafyomi.co.il/nedarim/insites/nd-dt-023.htm  But I have read other sources to the contrary, saying that kol nidre is not a beit din.

Comment: @mbloch I hope you are correct. It is almost Elul. It will take a while to digest such advice. BTW, I wonder why there is not more guidance in a typical siddur or machzor on davening alone.

Comment: @mbloch It is the 8th of Elul and I have yet to see any, much less " lots and lots of them".  Have you run across any?

Comment: @YehudaW I recently was made aware of a Koren machzor for those in time pressing situations which color-codes what is required, nice to have and optional https://korenpub.com/products/the-rimon-yom-kippur-mahzorhardcoverstandardashkenaz?variant=31287311958094 - beyond this I know of rabbanim preparing pamphlets but haven't seen them yet

Comment: @YehudaW if you are comfortable with Hebrew here is an example of instructions https://www.dropbox.com/s/xgkwem8dil3jrv0/Instructions%20short%20tefila.JPG?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Rav Yosef brings in the [Gemarra](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.4b?lang=bi) (Avodah Zarah 4B) that one who is davenning alone on Rosh Hashanah should avoid davenning Mussaf during the first three hours of the day; "Rav Yosef says: A person should not recite the additional prayers during the first three hours of the day on the first day of Rosh HaShana if he is praying individually, as, since the judgment of the entire world is reckoned then, perhaps the Heavenly court will scrutinize his actions and reject him." This is not normally brought up this time of year because it is atypical for people to daven alone on Rosh Hashanah; I'm curious to see what our Rabbis will say.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by not normally brought up, but the details of this rule are discussed in OC 591:8 https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A6%D7%90_%D7%97 and I've told people (generally those with daily childcare responsibilities) about it before.

Comment: This text provides information on davenning alone on Rosh Hashanah, and turns out that Rosh Hashanah is one of the Yomim Naraim.

Comment: That may be but it doesn't seem remotely similar to the publication the OP referenced

Answer (score 1):

OU has published the sections in the Artscroll, Koren and Birnbaum prayer books which are to be read when praying alone, based on the rulings of R Hershel Schachter and R Mordechai Willig.

- last two pages [here](https://assets.torahtidbits.com/2021/09/02160046/Nitzavim-Rosh-Hashana-1435-ROSH-HASHANA-SECTION.pdf) for Rosh Hashana
- pages 25-28 [here](https://assets.torahtidbits.com/2021/09/15090058/YK-Haazinu-Sukkot-Breishit-1436-YK-Section.pdf) for Yom Kippur

Answer (score 0):

First several pages of [Ohr Torah Stone's Condensed Machzor](https://ots.org.il/machzor/) has a detailed guide. They own the copyright but give free permission to distribute, so I'm hopefully allowed to paste their notes here:

> > Guide for those Davening without a Minyan on Yom Kippur YOM KIPPUR EVE 1) One may recite “Kol Nidrei” omitting the passage “על דעת המקום”
> > and omitting the line “שעבר עד יום כיפורים זה מיום כיפורים”2) Recite
> > Shehechiyanu3) Recite all blessings before and after the Shema through
> > the end of the Silent Amidah [without the Chatzi Kaddish]4) One may
> > recite the Selichot but without “*אל מלך... לכל קוראיך,” and “רחמנא...
> > קריב”—in addition, one should not say the public Viduy/Confession that
> > is found on page 10 through the top of page 12. 5) Recite Avinu
> > Malkeinu  6) Recite Aleinu and LeDavid Hashem Ori  SHACHARIT 1) One
> > recites everything until the Chatzi Kaddish 2) One does not recite any
> > Kaddish, nor “ברכו... לעולם ועד”3) Recite all the blessings before and
> > after the Shema till the end of the Silent Amidah [without Kedusha]4)
> > Regarding prayers that appear in the Chazzan's Repetition for
> > Shacharit one should not recite the public Viduy/Confession; one may
> > recite the Piyutim/ “פיוטים” on page 27 5) Recite Avinu Malkeinu,
> > Psalm of the Day (“Shir shel Yom”) and LeDavid Hashem Ori without the
> > Kaddish before or after6) Torah Reading O P TI O NAL TO RECITED O N OT
> > RECITE • “אתה הראת/אין כמוך... בקדושתו”• “אד-ני אד-ני... ונקה”•
> > “ריבונו של עולם... ולשלם”• Blessings before/after Aliya as well as
> > blessings before/after the Haftarah• Torah Readings and Haftarah7) One
> > can recite the Prayer for the Welfare of the State of Israel and the
> > Prayer for the Welfare of Israel’s Security Forces 8) Recite Yizkor
> > (if obligated) 9) Recite Ashrei 10) Optional to recite from “יהללו”
> > till “כקדם” 11) Recite the Silent Amidah for Musaf
> > *IN LIEU OF THIS PRAYER, WHEN PRAYING WITHOUT A MINYAN, IT IS PERMITTED TO RECITE WITH THE CANTILLATIONS SHEMOT 34:5-9. HALAKHICALLY
> > CONDENSED MACHZOR YOM KIPPUR (5782/2021 ONLY) • מחזור הלכתי מקוצר ליום
> > הכיפורים תשפ״ב בלבד iii 11) Regarding prayers that appear in the
> > Chazzan's Repetition for Musaf, one must recite the “Seder HaAvodah”
> > from “אמיץ כח/אתה כוננת” through “כל אלה בהיות ההיכל דורו ראו ושמחו”—
> > in addition, one should not recite the public Viduy/Confession One is
> > not obligated, but may also recite:• “ונתנה תוקף... קדושה בקודש”•
> > ״ושמו אחד״ ...״האוחז ביד”• “אוחילה... וגואלי”• “אמת מה נהדר... וכימה
> > מתימן. מראה כהן”• “כל אלה... ואל חטאתו”• “אלה אזכרה”• “תביאינו...
> > אל-הינו... כי רב הוא” MINCHA  Torah Reading O P TI O NAL TO RECITED O
> > N OT RECITE • “ויהי בנסוע... אד-ני אלו-הינו”• Blessings before/after
> > Aliya as well as blessings before/after the Haftarah• Torah Readings
> > and Haftorah1) Recite the Silent Amidah omitting the Chatzi Kaddish2)
> > Regarding prayers that appear in the Chazzan's Repetition for Mincha,
> > one should not recite the public Viduy/Confession. One may recite the
> > following, but is not obligated to do so:• “אמנת... מי כעמך ישראל”•
> > “אל נא... אתה תענה אד-ני אלו-הינו” NE'ILAH 1) Recite Ashrei and Uva
> > LeTzion2) Silent Amidah3) Regarding prayers that appear in the
> > Chazzan's Repetition for Ne'ilah, one should not recite the public
> > Viduy/Confession. One may recite the following, but is not obligated
> > to do so:• “אב ידך מנער... בצדק יושב כחם היום”• “שמע נא... נורא ואים.
> > קדוש”• All the Selichot for Ne'ilah with the exception of “*א-ל מלך...
> > לכל קוראיך”  4) Recite Avinu Malkeinu 5) Recite “שמע... הוא האלו-הים”
> > *IN LIEU OF THIS PRAYER, WHEN PRAYING WITHOUT A MINYAN, IT IS PERMITTED TO RECITE WITH THE CANTILLATIONS SHEMOT 34:5-9. HALAKHICALLY
> > CONDENSED MACHZOR YOM KIPPUR (5782/2021 ONLY) • מחזור הלכתי מקוצר ליום
> > הכיפורים תשפ״ב בלבד ivMAARIV FOR MOTZEI YOM KIPPUR  1) Recite Maariv
> > without “ברכו” and Kaddish 2) One may sound the Shofar when Yom Kippur
> > ends3) One may recite Kiddush Levanah outside if the moon is visible
> > and preferably recited with another person4) Recite Havdalah over a
> > cup of wine/grape juice with a candle lit prior to the onset of Yom
> > Kippur

Comment: Unlike the misleading title "condensed", davening alone saves so much time on minyan-only material that there is plenty of time to recite all the traditional piyyutim and slichos that are skipped in places to save time (see a sampling in the back of any Artscroll machzor). They should have put out an "expanded" machzor for this purpose. "Condensed" machzors are just for minyanim that are time limited

Comment: @DoubleAA thanks, *in hachi nami.* They made a condensed machzor for time-limited communal prayers, then added in "how much of this can an individual say." Hadn't really thought that through.